# Real-time updates Facebook app subscription issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I have been trying to subscribe to real-time updates for the past week and I have been unsuccessful.

When I do the HTTP post (using rest-client) to URL:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions`
...I get this error message as response:

`{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter object is required","type":"OAuthException"}}`

My header parameters were as follows:

```
access_token=***,
object=user,
fields=friends,
callback_url=https://aaa.appspot.com,
verify_token=(app secret key)
```

I'm not able to find where I'm going wrong.
Somebody please kindly guide/help me figure my mistake.
The below link was used as a reference.
http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/tutorial/bytopic/realtime_upd_02.php

Thanks you for your time in advance.

Comment: What action/objects do you have defined in your application settings?

Comment: @DMCS: I have "use", "form Submit" as actions and "websites" as object.... What does verify token mean??? Is it app secret key or access_token??

Comment: Hi DMCS,
Can you please give a example of an endpoint URL that receives both HTTP GET (for subscription verification) and POST (for actual change data) requests from Facebook.
pls.
I have a feeling thats where Im going wrong.
Thanks for the response .

Comment: Here's a koala example https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Realtime-Updates...download their code...at least it will give you an example to base off from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your request to https://graph.facebook.com/appid/subscriptions and not https://graph.facebook.com/subscriptions - although that might be an error in your question and not your code!

**EDIT: I just checked the markup for your question and you do have appid in the URL, it just wasn't displaying properly**

How are you getting the access token? You must use an application access token and not a user access token, i.e. retrieve the access token from `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ is the official documentation, that might be more up to date than the link you've been using.